# Use Strings and routes from a list

Tags: list, flutter

i have this list

```
List list = [
 {'id': '0', 'name': 'BMW', 'route': Bmw},
 {'id': '1', 'name': 'Audi', 'route': Audi},
```

];

and this body

```
return Column(
  children: list.map((name) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: RaisedButton(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
          ),
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text(
            name,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => route()),
            );
          },
        ),
),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

but not work, i need generate buttons with the name from the list and the route fro the list by clicking the button, sorry for my english xD

Comment: and you want to create 1000 routes when your app will have 1000 car makers?

Comment: no maybe 30 or 40

Comment: does not matter, how would each route differ? I mean widget layout (not presented data like images, technical details etc) - you should have only ONE route and pass different data to that route

Comment: every route (page) have a list with details

Comment: thats why I said that you should have only ONE route

Comment: maybe its better make lists and call only 1 route and call differrend lists? but  how i can push the id to the next route(site)?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Comment: but if i make a new class with title i need to set the title from my list to the new variable? or what, and this class come in my main?

Comment: they use `DetailScreen(todo: todos[index]),` - here `todos[index])` is an object passed to the new route holding all the data that will be shown on `DetailScreen`

Comment: hmm dont understand this :( can u make a example with my code?

Comment: i gave you a complete working code - i will not write your code for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
 child: Text(
            name,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
```

by

```
child: Text(
            name['name'],
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
```

Comment: cool thats work but the route dont work :( only route to first id

Answer (score 0):

for accessing name you have to use name['name'] field to access from map

and for navigation you can use NamedRoutes
refer this link

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes

and in 'route' just set route_name you want to navigate to

and for navigation through named Routes use

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, name['route']);
```

Comment: thats not work for me say type '_Type' is not a subtype of type 'String'